# Batch script that will allow to search a particular IP and change it to a new IP address in a .ini file

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch script, that will allow to search a particular ip and change it to a new ip address in a .ini file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below updated code, please let me know if you still face issues

```
 cls 
 @Echo Off 
 SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
 if exist new.ini ( del /s /q new.ini ) 
 set "search=1.1.1.1"
 set "search2=2.2.2.2"
 set "replace=7.7.7.7"
 set "replace2=8.8.8.8"
 for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (Apservice.ini) Do ( 
 Set "filevalue=%%a" 
 Set filevalue=!filevalue:%search%=%replace%!
 Set filevalue=!filevalue:%search2%=%replace2%!
 Echo !filevalue!>>new.ini 
 ) 
 move /y new.ini Apservice.ini 
 ause
```

Comment: Thanks prudviraj...i will try it out and let you know.

Comment: please note that you need to replace ip.ini with your .ini file name , i have tested this code and it is working fine , please let me know if u face issues

Comment: prudviraj, I tried the code and it is not working. It is getting stuck in the for loop. Essentially, there are four different services in the .ini file and I only need to change the IP for one of the services. How can I do that?

Comment: Actually, it does not replace with new ip address values. Below is the code I have.

Comment: cls
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist new.ini (
del /s /q new.ini
)

set "SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=1.1.1.1"
set "REPLACE_SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=7.7.7.7"

echo search for !SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS! ApService.ini
echo replace !REPLACE_SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS! ApService.ini if match found

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (Apservice.ini) Do (

Set "filevalue=%%a"

Set filevalue =!filevalue:%SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS%=%REPLACE_SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS%!

Echo !filevalue!>>new.ini

)

move /y new.ini Apservice.ini

Comment: i have solved the problem , it is working fine , issue is with space near set command

Comment: Thanks a lot prudviraj…One other question, I do have one more IP to change that is part of different service name within the same .ini file. This IP has the same string name as well. How do I include that as well within this code?

For e.g.

Service Name=ABC
SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=1.1.1.1 (Needs to change to 7.7.7.7) (Working as per above)

Service Name=XYZ
SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=2.2.2.2 (Needs to change to 4.4.4.4)

Comment: @Shiva r ,it would be easy for me to do that, i would recommend you to try , you have the required code, just need to modify a bit to meet your requirement , give it a try and if u are stuck at some point then revert .

Comment: I tried but it just changes one value only. any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Shiva r , adding one more search and replace variables similar to the one we did above would help , if that is not the case , then give your exact requirement with inputs details , i will look into it and see a way out. :)

Comment: Prudviraj,

Sure thanks. But my issue here is –That when I add a new search and replace string it only takes precedence for one of the service.  How do I specify which service to use from the file. I have two different Service names within the same .ini file and I need to replace with different IP address in both services. I researched in this forum and others but did not get any clues. Can you please help?

Comment: Prudviraj,Both are the same string.Prudviraj,

Essentially, both strings are have the same name. SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS. 

The file is 

Service_Name=Test 1
SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=1.1.1.1

Service_Name=Test 2
SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=2.2.2.2

Essentially, 1.1.1.1 will be replaced by 7.7.7.7 and 2.2.2.2 will be replaced by 8.8.8.8.

Comment: hi , if the same pattern needs two different values to be replaced then it would be a difficult task, but to better understand you problem and sneak a way through to find a solution provide complete details , then will try some way out

Comment: Hi Prudviraj,

I am once again providng the details. In the same .ini file, I have the following. 


SERVICE_NAME=Test1
SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=1.1.1.1
SERVICE_Name=Test2
SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=2.2.2.2

It’s the same pattern, but different service name in the same file. The script will locate values above and change 1.1.1.1 to 7.7.7.7 and 2.2.2.2 to 8.8.8.8

Comment: @Shiva r,done, try the updated code .. please vote up answer if it has helped you

Comment: Thanks prudviraj...Accepted the code...Really appreciate all the help you have provided.