# Batch script to find and replace same string in multiple services in same .ini file

Tags: batch-file

I needed to find and replace the ip address in a .ini file.  The issue in my previous question was I only needed to change one IP address within a service. Now, I have the same text variable in different service names under the same .ini file. Below are details.

I have the following.

```
SERVICE_NAME=Test1 
SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=1.1.1.1 
SERVICE_Name=Test2 
SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=2.2.2.2
```

It’s the same pattern, but different service name in the same file. The script will locate values above and change 1.1.1.1 to 7.7.7.7 and 2.2.2.2 to 8.8.8.8. I require some help in how to define the service to choose, since both text variables are the same.

Below is the post I used before.

[Batch script that will allow to search a particular IP and change it to a new IP address in a .ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042307/batch-script-that-will-allow-to-search-a-particular-ip-and-change-it-to-a-new-i/33044595?noredirect=1#comment54093007_33044595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET iniFile=some.ini
TYPE NUL>temp_file.ini
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN (%iniFile%) DO (
    SET currentLine=%%L
    REM ECHO !currentLine:~0,28!
    IF "!currentLine:~0,28!"=="SERVICE_L2TP_PEER_IPADDRESS=" (
        SET currentLine=!currentLine:1.1.1.1=7.7.7.7!
        SET currentLine=!currentLine:2.2.2.2=8.8.8.8!
    )
    ECHO !currentLine!>>temp_file.ini
)
MOVE /Y temp_file.ini %iniFile%
```

You'll have to replace `some.ini` with the proper path and file name of your ini file.

Comment: Michael,Thanks. Doesnt seem to work. it just generates a blank som.ini file.

Comment: You have so enter the correct path and file name here: `SET iniFile=` some.ini is just a placeholder.